# How to have pandoc leave percent signs alone?

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

I'm writing a few LaTeX commands inside a Markdown source that I would like to comment out using a percent sign `%`. Unfortunately, `pandoc` escapes that to a `\%` that is thus typeset instead of triggering a comment. Manually escaping it as `\%` doesn't change anything (and why should it?), so my question is how to *not* escape a `%` in a markdown source?

Comment: I'm aware I _could_ use a HTML-comment `<!-- ... -->` instead, but that is neither LaTeX-y, nor does it appear in the tex-source as comment

Answer (score 2):

Asking how to write a comment in Markdown starting with `%` is like asking how to write a HTML comment starting with a `%`. You just can't.

However, there are a few possibilities for comments:

1. The syntax of comments in Pandoc's Markdown is adopted from HTML, so the following works:

   ```
   <!-- my comment-->
   ```
2. Use inline TeX commands:

   ```
   \begin{comment}
   my comment
   \end{comment}
   ```
3. You can also (ab-)use [YAML Metadata blocks](http://pandoc.org/README.html#extension-yaml_metadata_block) as comments:

   ```
   my text

   ---
   c: my comment
   ---

   more text
   ```

   (Leaving out something folowed by a colon will work as well, giving you a warning however.)
4. You can write a [pandoc filter](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html) to remove constructs that you'd use as comments, e.g. code spans with the class `c`:

   ```
   `my comment`{.c}
   ```
5. Use a preprocessor like [gpp in front of pandoc](https://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/how-i-stopped-worring-and-started-using-markdown-like-tex/).
6. And yes, you can always fall back to perl scripts and regexes. But they have the danger of matching false positives and breaking your document...

Comment: you probably mean "You can't - without modifying `pandoc`'s source" ;) Too bad, forced escaping without any means for unescaping seems a bit impractical to me...

Comment: I opened [#2564](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2564) for this and propose that the LaTeX writer interprets `%%` as a literal `%` to be not escaped.

Comment: @TobiasKienzler I just came across exactly this issue. Did you find any solution? (other than doing a `\begin/\end comment` section that you mention in the ticket)

Comment: As there seems to be no way to do this more elegantly, I am now marking comments with %% and then run `perl -pi -e 's/\\%\\%/%/g;' file.tex` — Maybe this helps someone in the future.

Comment: @jan Unfortunately not :-/ Though I'd also use the `%%` trick